# Optimal strategy to defeat the wizard

Tags: code-challenge, optimization

In this game, you can look inside one box at a time chosen by you.  When you do that, you can see how many coins there are in that box.

The wizard has one last twist for you. At any point, you can choose to give up on this set of boxes and get him to start the whole process again (with a new random \$x\$). Of course, if you have looked in all the 9 boxes and you still have not found 10 coins you have no choice but to give up and start again. But you might want to give up earlier too. Sadly you never get any money back so your costs just carry on building.

Your goal is to devise a strategy that will get you the wish at the minimum expected cost. You should report your mean cost.

## Testing

Once you have chosen your strategy, you should run it until you get the wish 10,000 times and report the mean cost. If two answers have the same strategy, the one posted first wins. If two strategies have similar mean costs you may need to test it 100,000 or even more times to tell the difference.

## Input and output

There is no input in this challenge. The output is just the mean cost to get a wish. To test your code you will need to implement both the wizard and your strategy.

Comment: What's the distribution of x?

Comment: @Nitrodon Uniform over the integers 1…10.

Comment: Let S_1 be any strategy that works (for instance, always open all 9 boxes), and for all n>1, let S_n be the optimal strategy in the first round if all subsequent rounds are forced to use strategy S_{n-1}.  This will always converge to an optimal strategy.

Comment: @Nitrodon can you add an answer?

Comment: "There is no input in this challenge. The output is just the mean cost to get a wish." Isn't this just a puzzle and not a code challenge?  Code just serves the function of "hey, this is how I worked it out..." but in theory I could use pencil and paper....

Comment: @Jonah you need the code to get the approx mean if you can’t compute it exactly.

Comment: “there should be equal probability of assignment of coins to boxes from all possible assignments of *x* coins to 10 boxes”—does this count assignments of indistinguishable coins or distinguishable coins? For example, if *x* = 2, are there 55 possible assignments each with probability 1/55, or 100 possible assignments each with probability 1/100?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg.  Sorry this wasn’t clear. It is the latter.

Comment: @graffe I understand practically that might be the case, but in theory I can use any method I want.  Maybe I'm just being pedantic and the idea is "you're going to use code to solve it, and that will be what's interesting" but somehow logically it doesn't feel right that the deliverable is just a number and yet it is a code challenge.

Comment: @Jonah the deliverable is really the code in my view. You just judge the code by its output.

Comment: @Jonah I guess also these are solutions that can't really be found without code.

Comment: @Nitrodon How do we know the method you describe converges to the optimum? Is there an associated theorem?

Answer (score 6):

## Python, cost = \$\frac{654510644704}{387420489}\$ = 1689.4063770179175

An optimal strategy, computed and evaluated exactly with [this code](https://tio.run/##vVTJbsIwEL3nK@ZoG1PiVpUapFz7Bb2hHAIxxSpZ5IQ2CPHtdGyHhJAE9VRfvMx7M561OFa7PHt5K/TlotIi1xWkcbXztjpPYavjTaXyrIRG9N48eN4mLysI2wcifMaE4BDg5lNg8CqE5/3s1F7Chz7IpQe4jiVyTvZoFmMnkhcykwkHZC2BGLV4prDNNTgRqAx0nH1KtEHPvEcOOAIPWWKoPgff8ezTGO3s2e1Ot/yWupQJceiA0mVrY0wbqO2VHYbgg9yX0v6@ZVlPOSRHdHZOnhlzcIof7GGMdnWjWcD86k4PZ/UJo1CgxmO5aszPQDT@41FFA06B6PKQkoHArDZzo1KzTB08bfJ0TeprmCex7BZ9dYODesRwXjBmsQ9wJECFTQgx69AZwF1RPkk1NVmPi8f/ZRJSdwlJ45rcRhgTKMSQSWHxf2H@c9CEPxW1f4rYVLSGpQ2zEGuVYY0PZEkrTO6kbRs05iIsdmPezQEOxHYgpa7lsWeRYETRyo9s43Y9ttYy/nI4O9bmYQ@86G7CNVmhVVZ1GV31PmZKYeRz4eMJRQeTYTD9cLh2qKjLkp2Z9kYvl18) (which uses a similar Newton’s method search as a [comment of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250830/optimal-strategy-for-wandering-robots/250941#comment559237_250941) on your previous challenge, and is equivalent to [Nitrodon’s comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251029/optimal-strategy-to-defeat-the-wizard#comment559291_251029) on this one).

```python
import math
import random

def strategy(opened, found):
    return found >= [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9][opened]

count, mean, m2 = 0, 0.0, 0.0

for run in range(10000):
    cost = 0

    while True:
        coins = [0] * 10
        for i in range(random.randrange(1, 11)):
            coins[random.randrange(10)] += 1

        opened, found = 0, 0
        while found != 10 and opened != 9 and strategy(opened, found):
            found += coins[opened]
            cost += 2**opened
            opened += 1
        if found == 10:
            break

    count += 1
    delta = cost - mean
    mean += delta / count
    m2 += delta**2 * (1 - 1 / count)

mean_stdev = math.sqrt(m2 / (count * (count - 1)))
print(f"{mean} ± {mean_stdev}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJbboMwEPz3Kab5wtRJgPSVSvQU/YuiigaToAZDjWkVRT1Ur9CLpWvMQ6hS/WHWOzuz4zXVyRxKtZpXp@p0ueRFVWqDIjEH1sU6UWlZMJbKDLXRiZH7k1dWUslUICsblfJHBlpamkYrl8JTjE0gEAmsBG4EbgXuBO4FHgTW243jbxnbUbURKGSiaI8Qg1jBwm2MZaWGbhRyZX3spRcGtLqGu7I2lsDa0@chP0o860Y61FXkqoa1soWPMBgAq5uPqu6OC/vp2giEIeej0qC2@Vsb8C2uY4RsqJ6Mp7vTADqjDroiWgCS6ig2sW7P/456vIYVod7OWj/VqWkaElVEvu/gCdp1bd33uTzrfVtz04avWiZvrJs@vdzITOXRJIhdv3n7oG3eBrbK4UtHc0g05H0/ovfxQiKGfQ1nzHJfapPKDxK2/@SiftfGI@ISnuvv9wExOees0rkyXjY7W@4Xfr5xHlW@Zvxy@QU)

Comment: Also, how do we know we should always open the boxes starting at box 1 without missing any out or doing them in a different order?

Comment: @graffe Any strategy that opens boxes out of order will be beaten by a modified version of that strategy that opens boxes in order, which gets the same distribution of finish times for less money.

Comment: This is a clever solution. Does it crucially rely on monotonicity? That is that more coins found in a box is always better. If we changed the problem so box 10 could also be opened and you got the wish if there are a total of 3 or 7 coins in the boxes could you use the same approach?

Comment: @graffe Monotonicity is only used to compress the solution to a list of 9 numbers. The same approach would work fine for the changed problem, you’d just need to write out the 9×10 boolean matrix instead.

Comment: How about if we change the problem so that looking in box i tells you the sum of the coin counts for boxes 1 to i? I guess in this case you might want to skip some boxes which makes finding an optimal solution more difficult?

Comment: @graffe Not particularly. It’s pretty hard to stump a computer with a system of ~100 equations.

Comment: Thanks. I added a bounty for this as it seems a fun extra detail.

Comment: It turns out I am supposed to ask it as a separate question

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you have a bug in the way your strategy loop handles boxes and coins. Because you open the first box, then check the strategy function before allocating coins and cost of that box, in the next iteration your strategy function is checking the new # of boxes with the previous box's coins. Moving the base case out of the loop and changing the order to open -> cost -> found -> check strategy -> repeat fixes the problem. It also stops that while loop from hanging when you have `found >= [1, ...` in the strategy.

Comment: @Renaldi There’s no such bug. The strategy function is called in the `while` loop’s condition, which runs before the first box is opened and the coins are updated. If you have `found >= [1, ...` in the strategy, that corresponds to the real but bone-headed strategy where you always restart before opening any boxes, which will indeed result in an infinite loop—so don’t do that.

Comment: @Renaldi Perhaps your point of confusion is that Python arrays are 0-indexed, unlike R’s 1-indexed arrays.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Thanks for clarifying! My misunderstanding was actually that I assumed you were treating the number of open boxes as 0-indexed, and that the first element of the strategy vector was what you'd do given the number of coins in the first box, at index zero. This made sense to me since my code starts with the first box open. I see now how you handled that condition. PS: While the language's indexing wasn't the issue for me this time, it often is: R is 1-indexed, but Rcpp is 0-indexed like C++, and for extra fun, Rcpp sugar functions are sometimes 1-indexed to match R

Answer (score 3):

## R / Rcpp: 1688.758 ± 0.740

Evaluated on 15 million simulated games. Error values are a bootstrap confidence interval with 10,000 iterations. The learned policy matches Anders' optimal policy.

### Method

The policy to minimize cost was learned using double n-step SARSA, a reinforcement learning algorithm. The optimal policy was learned by training 15 agents in parallel, where each agent's current policy was replaced by the average of all agents' policies every 100,000 actions. The optimal policy was found in about 4.5e8 actions, or ~150,000 epsiodes at 3000 actions per episode.

The algorithm's learning parameters were set as follows: discount factor `gamma = 0.17258`, learning rate `alpha = 0.3904111`, and epsilon-greedy action selection `epsilon = 0.2702468`. I originally wrote the algorithm as an n-step SARSA but settled on `n = 1`. The learning parameters were found using model-based Bayesian optimization. I used 105 points for the initial design and searched 50 sequentially proposed points.

#### Reward Shaping

When reaching a new state by opening a box, the agent's reward was the sum of the value of the found coins, where coin `n` is worth \$2^{n-1}\$, minus the cost of the opened box. When giving up the set of boxes and starting over, the agent's reward was the negative sum of the value of the coins it had found during the episode if the episode was possible to have won; otherwise, the agent's reward was zero. In all cases a constant reward of `-1` was applied.

### Learned Policy

The below photo shows the policy learned by the agent. A black square indicates that if the agent has collected the corresponding number of coins by opening that many boxes, it will continue to open boxes. Otherwise, the agent will give up the set of boxes.
[image: Learned policy]

### Code

**R code to initialize the state-action space**

```
#' Initialize the State-Action Space
initStateSpace <- function(){
  
  #Generate full grid
  space = expand.grid(
    numOpenBox = 0:9,
    numCoins = 0:10,
    act = c(0:1)
  )
  
  #Remove states where no boxes are open, but positive coins found
  inds = (space$numOpenBox == 0) & (space$numCoins > 0)
  space = space[!inds,]
  
  #Remove states where all boxes are open, but action is open box
  inds = (space$numOpenBox == 9) & (space$act == 1)
  space = space[!inds,]
  
  #Add columns for value
  space$valueA = 0
  space$valueB = 0
  
  #Return
  return(as.matrix(space))
  
}
```

**Rcpp code for the algorithm, simulation, and evaluation**
Note: Because the episode is cyclical, I opted not to handle updating the state-action values for pairs within n steps of the terminal state.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//* Place Coins in Boxes
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector setCoins() {
  
  //Sample number of coins
  NumericVector coinSet = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  NumericVector boxSet = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  NumericVector nCoins = Rcpp::sample(coinSet, 1);
  NumericVector boxInds = Rcpp::sample(boxSet, nCoins[0], true);
  
  //Assign coins to boxes
  NumericVector out (10);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < boxInds.length(); j++){
      if(i == boxInds[j] - 1){
        out[i] = out[i] + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  
  //Return
  return(out);
  
}

//* Subset State-Action Space by State
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix subsetSpace(
    NumericVector state, 
    NumericMatrix stateSpace
) {
  
  //Find rows that match the input state
  LogicalVector inds (stateSpace.nrow(), false);
  for(int i = 0; i < inds.length(); i++){
    if(stateSpace(i, 0) == state[0] & stateSpace(i, 1) == state[1]){
      inds[i] = true;
    }
  }
  
  //Subset the state-action space to the input state
  NumericMatrix out(sum(inds), stateSpace.ncol());
  for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < inds.length(); i++){
    if(inds[i]){
      out(j, _) = stateSpace(i, _);
      j = j + 1;
    }
  }
  
  //Return
  return(out);
  
}

//* Choose action
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double chooseAction(
    NumericVector state, 
    NumericMatrix stateSpace, 
    double epsilon
) {
  
  //Subset state-action space to input state
  NumericMatrix localSpace = subsetSpace(state, stateSpace);
  
  //Epsilon-greedy action selection
  double action;
  if(Rcpp::runif(1, 0.0, 1.0)[0] <= epsilon){
    IntegerVector actionSet = Rcpp::seq(0, localSpace.nrow() - 1);
    IntegerVector actionInd = Rcpp::sample(actionSet, 1);
    action = localSpace(actionInd[0], 2);
  } else {
    NumericVector value = (localSpace(_, 3) + localSpace(_, 4)) / 2;
    int actionInd = Rcpp::which_max(value);
    action = localSpace(actionInd, 2);
  }
  
  //Return
  return(action);
  
}

//* Calculate Reward
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double calculateReward(NumericVector state, NumericVector boxState) {
  double reward = 0;
  int openBoxes = state[0];
  int coinsFound;
  if(state[2] == 1) {
    
    //Reward for opening box is value of coins found minus cost of box
    coinsFound = boxState[openBoxes];
    reward += -pow(2, openBoxes);
    for(int j = 0; j < coinsFound; j++){
      reward += pow(2, state[1] + j);
    }
    
  } else {
    
    //Reward for shuffling is regret if the game was possible to complete
    if(sum(boxState) == 10 & boxState[9] == 0) {
      for(int j = 0; j < state[1]; j++){
        reward += -pow(2, j);
      }
    }
    
  }
  
  //Constant negative reward
  reward += -1;
  
  //Return
  return(reward);
  
}

//* Take Action
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector takeAction(NumericVector state, NumericVector boxState) {
  double reward = calculateReward(state, boxState);
  if(state[2] == 1) {
    int openBoxes = state[0];
    state[0] = state[0] + 1;
    state[1] = state[1] + boxState[openBoxes];
    state[2] = -1;
    state[3] = reward;
  } else {
    state = {0, 0, 1, reward};
  }
  return(state);
}

//* Find State-Action Index
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int findStateIndex(
    NumericVector state,
    NumericMatrix stateSpace
) {
  int index = NA_INTEGER;
  for(int i = 0; i < stateSpace.nrow(); i++){
    if(stateSpace(i, 0) == state[0] & stateSpace(i, 1) == state[1] & stateSpace(i, 2) == state[2]){
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return(index);
}

//* Create Record
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix createRecord(int n) {
  NumericVector v (2 * (n + 1), -1.0); 
  return(NumericMatrix (n + 1, 2, v.begin()));
}

//* Copy State to Record
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix copyToRecord(
  NumericVector state,
  NumericMatrix stateSpace,
  NumericMatrix record
) {
  
  //Find index of state-action pair
  int pairInd = findStateIndex(state, stateSpace);
  
  //Write to first open index if possible
  bool openSlot = false;
  for(int i = 0; i < record.nrow(); i++){
    if(record(i, 0) == -1){
      record(i, 0) = pairInd;
      record(i, 1) = state[3];
      openSlot = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  //Otherwise, shift down and write
  if(!openSlot){
    for(int i = 1; i < record.nrow(); i++){
      record(i - 1, 0) = record(i, 0);
      record(i - 1, 1) = record(i, 1);
    }
    record(record.nrow() - 1, 0) = pairInd;
    record(record.nrow() - 1, 1) = state[3];
  }
  
  //Return
  return(record);
  
}

//* Calculate Return
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double calculateReturn(
  NumericMatrix record,
  double gamma
) {
  double g = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i < record.nrow(); i++){
    g = g + pow(gamma, i - 1) * record(i, 1);
  }
  return(g);
}

//* Update State-Action Value
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix updateStAcValue(
  NumericMatrix record,
  NumericMatrix stateSpace,
  double gamma,
  double alpha
) {
  
  //Double SARSA
  //Randomly select A or B values to update
  IntegerVector vSet = {0, 1};
  vSet = Rcpp::sample(vSet, 1);
  vSet.push_back(1 - vSet[0]);
  
  //Shift vSet to match value column numbers
  vSet = vSet + 3;
  
  //Update state-action value
  int n = record.nrow() - 1;
  double G = calculateReturn(record, gamma);
  G = G + pow(gamma, n) * stateSpace(record(n, 0), vSet[0]);
  stateSpace(record(0, 0), vSet[1]) += alpha * (G - stateSpace(record(0, 0), vSet[1])); 
  
  //Return
  return(stateSpace);
  
}

//* Learn Policy
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix learnPolicy(
    NumericMatrix stateSpace,
    double gamma,
    double alpha,
    double epsilon,
    int n,
    int iters
) {
  
  //Loop episodes
  int i = 0;
  while(true){
  
    //Initialize n-step Sarsa
    NumericMatrix record = createRecord(n);
    NumericVector boxState = setCoins();
    NumericVector state = {0, 0, 1, 0};
    
    //Record initial state
    record(0, 0) = findStateIndex(state, stateSpace);
    
    //Complete episode
    double t = 0;
    double tau = 0;
    double T = R_PosInf;
    bool done = false;
    while(!done) {
       
      //Take action
      if(state[2] == 1){
        state = takeAction(state, boxState);
        state[2] = chooseAction(state, stateSpace, epsilon);
      } else if(state[2] == 0) {
        state = takeAction(state, boxState);
        boxState = setCoins();
      }
      
      //Update record
      record = copyToRecord(state, stateSpace, record);
      
      //Update state-action values
      tau = t - n + 1;
      if(tau >= 0){
        stateSpace = updateStAcValue(record, stateSpace, gamma, alpha);
      }
      
      //Complete
      t = t + 1;
      if(state[1] == 10){
        done = true;
      }
      
      //Break loop when all iterations are complete
      i += 1;
      if(i >= iters){
        break;
      }
      
    }
    
    //Break loop when all iterations are complete
    if(i >= iters){
      break;
    }
    
  }
  
  //Return
  return(stateSpace);
  
}

//* Evaluate Policy
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector evaluatePolicy(
  NumericMatrix stateSpace,
  int iters
) {
  NumericVector out (iters, 0.0);
  for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++){
    NumericVector boxState = setCoins();
    NumericVector state = {0, 0, 1, 0};
    bool done = false;
    while(!done) {
      if(state[2] == 1){
        out[i] += pow(2, state[0]);
        state = takeAction(state, boxState);
        state[2] = chooseAction(state, stateSpace, 0.0);
      } else if(state[2] == 0) {
        state = {0, 0, 1, 0};
        boxState = setCoins();
      }
      if(state[1] == 10){
        done = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return(out);
}
```

**R code to learn and evaluate policy**
Learning parameters found using Model-Based Bayesian Optimization

```
#Create a policy by parallel RL
#Learns the optimal policy in 4.5e8 actions over 15 agents
#Or ~150,000 episodes total at 3000 actions per episode
#Agents replace their policies with the average policy every 100,000 actions
numAgents = 15
for(i in 1:300){
  
  #Generate initial policies
  if(i == 1){
    policy = lapply(1:numAgents, function(c){
      learnPolicy(
        initStateSpace(),
        n = 1,
        gamma = 0.17258,
        alpha = 0.3904111,
        epsilon = 0.2702468,
        iters = 1500000 / numAgents
      )
    })
    policy = Reduce("+", policy) / numAgents
    
  } else {
    
  #Use the average of the initial policies to seed new agents
    policy = lapply(1:numAgents, function(c){
      learnPolicy(
        policy,
        n = 1,
        gamma = 0.17258,
        alpha = 0.3904111,
        epsilon = 0.2702468,
        iters = 1500000 / numAgents
      )
    })
    policy = Reduce("+", policy) / numAgents
    
  }

}

#Evaluate policy over 15mil episodes
summary(evaluatePolicy(policy, 15000000))
```

Comment: Really great to see this alternative method. Your score is exactly the score I get when trying to reproduce Anders' solution.

Comment: @graffe Thank you! It's nice knowing that there are so many creative ways to arrive at the same result.

Comment: Do you know why you don't get closer to 1689.4?

Comment: @graffe I used a SARSA variant, which is an online learning algorithm. Online learners learn while experiencing the environment, so they have to take exploratory actions in order to find good policies, and typically learn more conservative policies, e.g. you wouldn't walk exactly along a cliff edge if you knew you might randomly step off it. There are ways to address this, but the policy was already so close to optimal that I didn't think it was necessary. You can see from Anders' solution that the only difference between the learned policy and the optimal is the (2, 2) coordinate in my plot.

Comment: If you had time, I would be really interested to see how you could improve the score even further.

Comment: @graffe I updated the method showing how the optimal policy can be found much more quickly using parallel RL and tuning the learning parameters.

Comment: This is very impressive. Out of interest, why sarsa and not PPO?

Comment: A practical reason is that PPO is a more flexible model, and typically the "best" option is to choose the least complex model that solves the problem. Personally though, I used SARSA because it's a fun algorithm to code and it's been a while since I've had a good problem to use it on