# Strategy: The cunning cousin witch

Tags: code-challenge

The [wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251029/optimal-strategy-to-defeat-the-wizard) has a cunning cousin who is a witch. She looks down on the wizard, regarding him and his puzzles as mathematically naive.  On reading his latest puzzle, she scorned him for always asking discrete problems with what she (unfairly) characterises as simple solutions, where the real, proper question should be continuous. To prove her point she poses the following version of the wizard's puzzle. (He reluctantly permits the partial plagiarism.)

Consider the following setup. A cunning witch has a real number line stretching from 0 to 10 which is hidden from you.  Also hidden from you she chooses a random integer \$x \in \{0, \dots, 10\}\$ and places that many points onto the number line uniformly at random. To be more precise, she places each of the \$x\$ points independently and uniformly at random onto the number line.  Your task is to prove that \$x = 10\$ and if you do the witch will grant you what she promises is a much better wish than what her cousin can provide.

In this game, you can at each step choose a floating point number \$y\$ and the witch will tell you the number of points on the number line with value less than or equal to \$y\$.

However the witch, being at least as evil as her cousin, will not let you choose a number larger than \$9\$. This might still be OK as you might still find 10 points and in fact the only way to be granted the wish is to have found all 10 points with values 9 or less.

The cost for choosing a floating point number \$y\$ is \$2^{y}\$ dollars.   At any point, you can choose to give up on this set of points and get her to start the whole process again (with a new random \$x\$). Of course, if you choose the number 9 and you still have not found 10 points you have no choice but to give up and start again. But you might want to give up after having chosen a number smaller than 9. Sadly you never get any money back so your costs just carry on building.

Your goal is to devise a strategy that will get you the wish at the minimum expected cost. You should report your mean cost.

## Testing

Once you have chosen your strategy, you should run it until you get the wish 10,000 times and report the mean cost. If two answers have the same strategy, the one posted first wins. If two strategies have similar mean costs you may need to test it 100,000 or even more times to tell the difference.  Of course if you can directly compute the expected cost, all the better.

## Input and output

There is no external input in this challenge. The output is just the mean cost to get a wish. To test your code you will need to implement both the witch and your strategy.

## What's a naive score?

If you just choose 9 each time then it will take you \$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{11} \cdot \frac{9}{10}^{10}} \approx 31.5\$  tries to find 10 points. This will cost you approximately \$16152.4\$ dollars.  How much better can you do?

## Notes

You can assume that floating numbers are precise mathematical real numbers when evaluating your code and that the random number generator from your favourite library is perfect (except please don't use the default [rand()](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/ISO-Random.html) in C which is truly terrible).

Comment: is it ok if the witch never places a point on exactly 10? only arbitrarily close to 10? asking because js random is [0,1) and not [0,1]

Comment: @thejonymyster Yes that is fine.

Comment: @graffe I suspect that if you treat this as your linked Wizard question where the number of boxes approaches infinity, the optimal policy for this question should be for the agent to continue if points found > length of line searched. Then since points are found in integer amounts, you can search the line in integer amounts, which brings you back to the Wizard problem. I.e., if you randomly place points on the number line and then bin in integer amounts, the most efficient binning is equivalent to the Wizard question

Comment: *the random number generator from your favourite library is perfect* which most likely calls C `rand()` under the hood. But then you ban calling `rand()` explicitly from C?

Comment: @Noodle9 Which one are you thinking that calls rand()?

Comment: More to the point, are you sure none of them call `rand()`?

Comment: @Noodle9 I don't know one for another language that does but if it does exist, you should avoid it!

Comment: So **all** ("all" being every single language that may be used in answering this challenge) of them don't use `rand()`?

Answer (score 4):

## R / Rcpp: 2641.844 ± 1.132

Evaluated on 15 million simulated games. Bounds are a 95% bootstrap confidence interval with 10,000 iterations.

Posting on behalf of my cousin who looks down on reinforcement learning, as in my solution to the Wizard's puzzle. "Reward shaping? If it's any good you've already solved the problem." To prove her point she poses the following heuristic solution to the witch's puzzle.

### Method

The policy was learned using a genetic algorithm with an initial population of 500 chromosomes. Fitness for each chromosome was calculated by evaluating its corresponding policy over 50,000 games.

All chromosomes with fitness above the median (the half of the chromosomes with the lowest mean evaluated cost) were selected at random to reproduce, and the remaining chromosomes were discarded. Reproduction continued until the population returned to its original size.

The crossover operator was a uniform heuristic crossover with an expected crossover rate of 50%, and an expected scaling coefficient of 0.5. Because my crossover operator chooses uniform random values for the crossover rate and scaling coefficient every time it is called, I chose to only produce one offspring per operation to increase offspring randomness / exploration.

The mutation operator was defined to replace target genes with uniform random values, and the mutation rate was set to 0.001.

### Policy Representation

My goal was to do as well as possible with a minimalist policy representation, so each chromosome is a numeric vector length 20. For a chromosome notated \$[p_{0}, p_{1}, ... , p_{10}, p_{11}, ... , p_{19}]\$, its corresponding policy is calculated as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & p_{11}\\
    p_{0} + p_{1} & p_{12}\\
    p_{0} + ... + p_{2} & p_{13}\\
    . & .\\
    . & .\\
    . & .\\
    p_{0}+...+p_{10} & p_{19}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The zero-indexed policy matrix, \$p\$, is interpreted as follows: Let \$\lambda\$ be the length of the number line searched, starting at zero. For \$n\$, the number of points found, if \$\lambda \leq p(n, 0)\$ then \$\lambda = lambda + p(n, 1)\$, otherwise reset.

In other words, the policy describes a distinct rate at which the line should be searched, \$p(n, 1)\$, given it has found \$n\$ points before having searched \$p(n, 0)\$ of the line.

### Learned Policy

After 200 generations, I selected the chromosome with the highest fitness, whose policy is approximately:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.00 & 1.07\\
    0.90 & 0.00\\
    1.74 & 2.46\\
    2.52 & 2.65\\
    3.25 & 4.11\\
    4.66 & 1.65\\
    4.66 & 2.91\\
    5.67 & 9.00\\
    9.00 & 5.58\\
    9.00 & 2.78\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This policy slowly searches the first half of the line until it finds enough points that it is worth searching the remainder of the line. At that point, it searches large chunks of the line to minimize cost. If it doesn't find enough points early on, it will reset (even though it may have been possible to find all 10 points).

For a more intuitive understanding of why the policy works and how it defined good step sizes, suppose we calculate the cost of searching some amount of the number line given we have already searched \$\lambda\$ as

$$
\text{Line per Cost} = \frac{p(n, 1)}{2^{p(n, 1) + \lambda}}
$$

From the formula we can see that as \$\lambda\$ increases, the cost of searching the additional \$p(n, 1)\$ also increases.

To understand this policy, consider when \$\lambda = p(n,0)\$, which corresponds to the worst scenario for which the policy will continue to search the line. Plotting the line per cost vs. the number of points found gives the below black points.

The blue points are \$\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\$, which corresponds to the line per cost given by searching the number line in units of one if you expect to find one point in each unit.

[image: LineSearchedPerCost]

So from the plot we can see that the learned policy has worst case preferences that nearly match what you get if you expect to find a point every time you search one unit of the number line. Note: Though the learned policy does not match \$\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\$ for the \$n = 1\$ case, repeated testing shows that skipping over the case where only one point has been found tends to improve the policy's score.

### Convergence Rate

I chose learning parameters to provide a smooth descent towards an optimal solution, and in the plot of the learning curve below that the population appears to find local minimums around the 20th and 30th generations before setting into the learned policy area somewhere between generations 100 and 150.

[image: Learning_Curve]

### Code

**Rcpp Code to Define the Genetic Algorithm**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//* Generate Points
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector setPoints() {
  
  //Sample number of points
  NumericVector pointSet = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  int numPts = Rcpp::sample(pointSet, 1)[0];
  
  //Return
  return(Rcpp::runif(numPts, 0.0, 10.0));
  
}

//* Generate Chromosome
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector generateChromosome() {
  return(Rcpp::runif(20, 0.0, 2.0));
}

//* Crossover
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector crossover(
  NumericVector x,
  NumericVector y
) {
  
  //Parameters
  NumericVector params = Rcpp::runif(2, 0.0, 1.0);
  NumericVector randVals = Rcpp::runif(x.length(), 0.0, 1.0);
  LogicalVector doCross = (randVals <= params[0]);
  
  //Apply crossover
  NumericVector offspring = clone(x);
  for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
    if(doCross[i]){
      NumericVector v = {params[1] * (x[i] - y[i]) + x[i]};
      v = Rcpp::clamp(0.0, v, 9.0);
      offspring[i] = v[0];
    }
  }
  
  //Return
  return(offspring);
  
}

//* Mutate
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector mutate(NumericVector x, double rate) {
  NumericVector x_new = clone(x);
  NumericVector randVals = Rcpp::runif(x.length(), 0.0, 1.0);
  LogicalVector doMutate = (randVals <= rate);
  for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
    if(doMutate[i]){
      x_new[i] = Rcpp::runif(1, 0.0, 9.0)[0];
    }
  }
  return(x_new);
}

//* Chromosome to Policy
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix chromToPolicy(NumericVector x) {
  NumericVector policy = clone(x);
  double sumVal = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    sumVal += x[i];
    if(sumVal > 9){
      sumVal = 9;
    }
    policy[i] = sumVal;
  }
  policy[0] = 0.0;
  policy.attr("dim") = Dimension(10, 2);
  return(as<NumericMatrix>(policy));
}

//* Evaluate
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector evaluatePolicy(
    NumericVector x,
    int iters,
    int maxCost = -1
) {

  //Convert chromosome to policy
  NumericMatrix policy = chromToPolicy(x);
  
  //Run episodes
  NumericVector out (iters, 0.0);
  bool earlyStop = false;
  for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++){

    //Initialize values
    NumericVector points = setPoints();
    double lineSearched = 0;
    int ptsFound = 0;

    //Begin episode
    bool done = false;
    while(!done) {

      //Step forward if in policy
      if(policy(ptsFound, 0) >= lineSearched){
        lineSearched += policy(ptsFound, 1);
        if(lineSearched > 9){
          lineSearched = 9;
        }
        out[i] += pow(2, lineSearched);
        ptsFound = sum(points <= lineSearched);
        
      } else {
        
      //Otherwise, reset
        points = setPoints();
        lineSearched = 0;
        ptsFound = 0;
      }
      
      //Reset when line searched but fewer than 10 points found
      if(lineSearched == 9 & ptsFound < 10){
        points = setPoints();
        lineSearched = 0;
        ptsFound = 0;
      }
      
      //Exit conditions
      if(ptsFound == 10){
        done = true;
      }

      //Early stop condition
      if((maxCost >= 0 & out[i] >= maxCost)){
        out[i] = NA_REAL;
        earlyStop = true;
        done = true;
      }

    }
    if(earlyStop){
      break;
    }
  }
  return(out);
}
```

**R Code to Run the Algorithm**

```
#----- Initialize Population -----

#Generate seed population
#Because random chromosomes are often slow to evaluate
#Seed with random chromosome s.t. max(cost) < 50,000
size <- 500
population <- t(sapply(1:size, function(c){
  generateChromosome()
}))

#Calculate fitness
fitness <- sapply(1:nrow(population), function(i){
  mean(evaluatePolicy(population[i,], 50000, 50000))
})

#Increase yield
population <- population[!is.na(fitness),]
while(TRUE){
  
  #New population
  newPopulation <- t(sapply(1:size, function(c){
    generateChromosome()
  }))
  newFitness = sapply(1:nrow(newPopulation), function(i){
    mean(evaluatePolicy(newPopulation[i,], 50000, 50000))
  })
  population <- rbind(population, newPopulation[!is.na(newFitness),])
  
  #End
  if(nrow(population) >= size){
    rm(newFitness, newPopulation)
    break
  }
  
}

#----- Evolve -----

#Parameters
rounds <- 200

#Iterate over generations
for(i in 1:rounds){
  
  #Calculate fitness
  fitness <- sapply(1:nrow(population), function(i){
    mean(evaluatePolicy(population[i,], 50000, 100000))
  })
  
  #Subset population
  population <- population[which(fitness <= median(fitness, na.rm = TRUE)),]
  
  #Crossover
  population <- rbind(population, t(sapply(1:(size - nrow(population)), function(i){
    inds = sample(1:nrow(population), 2, FALSE)
    crossover(population[inds[1],], population[inds[2],])
  })))
  
  #Mutate
  population <- t(sapply(1:nrow(population), function(i){
    mutate(population[i,], rate = 0.001)
  }))
  
}
```

Comment: Do you think it's possible to close the gap to the optimal strategy?

Comment: It really seems like it should be possible, but I've been working it since I posted and haven't been able to beat ~2640. I've tried removing the monotonic assumption, increasing the flexibility of the policy, and increasing the complexity of the genetic operators. No joy

Answer (score 3):

## Python, score = 2610.6431 (2610.5938 with 400 guess values)

Finds the optimal policy over a discrete set of equally spaced possible guesses (200 by default).

Here's a plot of new guess vs old guess for each number of found points; a guess of 0 means resetting. Make of it what you will.

[image: policy plots]

```python
import itertools
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom

bound = 16153
samples = 200

g = np.linspace(0, 9, samples)

def logsumexp(x):
    m = x.max()
    return np.log(np.sum(np.exp(x - m))) + m

def init_trans(samples):
    print("computing transition matrix...\n")
    trans = np.full((samples, 10, samples, 11), float('-inf'))
    g = np.linspace(0, 9, samples)
    for i0 in range(samples - 1):
        print(f"computing row {i0} of {samples}", end='\r', flush=True)
        g0 = g[i0]
        for n in range(10):
            k = np.arange(n, 11)
            u = np.zeros(k.shape) if i0 == 0 else binom(k, g0 / 10).logpmf(n)
            for i1 in range(i0 + 1, samples):
                g1 = g[i1]
                d = binom(k - n, (g1 - g0) / (10 - g0))
                for m in range(n, 11):
                    v = d.logpmf(m - n)
                    trans[i0,n,i1,m] = logsumexp(u + v)
    print()
    trans -= trans.max(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    trans = np.exp(trans)
    trans /= trans.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    return trans

trans_file= f'trans_{samples}.npy'
try:
    trans = np.load(trans_file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    trans = init_trans(samples)
    np.save(trans_file, trans)

def get_policy(trans):

    print("estimating policy...")
    values_file = f"values_{samples}.npy"
    policy_file = f"values_{samples}.npy"
    grad = np.zeros((samples, 11))
    values = np.zeros((samples, 11))
    policy = np.zeros((samples, 11), dtype=np.int64)
    x = bound
    while True:
        values[-1,:-1] = x
        grad[-1,:-1] = 1
        for i0 in range(samples - 2, -1, -1):
            for n in range(10):
                g1 = g[i0+1:]
                v1 = 2 ** g1 + np.einsum('ij, ij -> i', trans[i0,n,i0+1:,n:], values[i0+1:,n:])
                di = np.argmin(v1)
                i1 = i0 + di + 1
                if v1[di] <= x:
                    values[i0,n] = v1[di]
                    grad[i0,n] = np.sum(trans[i0,n,i1,n:] * grad[i1,n:])
                    policy[i0,n] = i1
                else:
                    values[i0,n] = x
                    grad[i0,n] = 1
                    policy[i0,n] = 0
        if values[0,0] >= x:
            break
        x += (values[0,0] - x) / (1 - grad[0,0])
    print(f"computed cost = {x}")
    return values, policy

values_file = f"values_{samples}.npy"
policy_file = f"policy_{samples}.npy"
try:
    values, policy = np.load(values_file), np.load(policy_file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    values, policy = get_policy(trans)
    np.save(values_file, values)
    np.save(policy_file, policy)

for i in range(10):
    plt.subplot(2, 5, i + 1)
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, samples), policy[:,i], color='blue')
plt.show()

print('running simulations...')

mean_cost = 0
cost_m2 = 0
for t in itertools.count():

    cost = 0

    while True:
        n = random.randrange(11)
        p = [10 * random.random() for _ in range(n)]
        i0 = 0
        f0 = 0
        done = False
        while True:
            i1 = int(policy[i0,f0])
            if i1 == 0:
                break
            g1 = g[i1]
            assert (0 <= g1 <= 9)
            cost += 2 ** g1
            f1 = sum(1 for x in p if x <= g1)
            if f1 == 10:
                done = True
                break
            if i1 == len(g) - 1:
                break
            i0 = i1
            f0 = f1
        if done:
            break

    mean_cost1 = mean_cost + (cost - mean_cost) / (t + 1.)
    cost_m2 += (cost - mean_cost) * (cost - mean_cost1)
    mean_cost = mean_cost1
    if t % 1000 == 0:
        print(f"{t} trials run, cost = {mean_cost} ± {np.sqrt(cost_m2 / (t + 1) ** 2):.3f}")
```

Comment: This is a huge improvement. I wonder how much further it can go.

Comment: I get "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  trans -= trans.max(axis=-1, keepdims=True)"

Comment: @graffe You can just ignore the warning, but I might look into it later.

Comment: Weird how for some counts of found points, a higher old guess can result in a lower new guess.

Comment: @xnor, I guess if you have a higher old guess then things are less promising so you might want to gather more information before committing.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, score= ~6,081.9

Guesses each number 1-9. Aborts if the number found is less than 0.8 * number.

Anyone is free to copy this answer and further optimize the parameters (0.8 abort limit and 1.0 step size) or of course modify anything else.

```rs
use rand;
use rand::{Rng, RngCore};

struct Which {
    rng: rand::rngs::ThreadRng,
    numbers: Vec<f32>,
    score: f32
}

impl Which {
    fn new(rng: rand::rngs::ThreadRng) -> Which {
        return Which{rng: rng, numbers: vec![], score: 0.0};
    }

    fn regenerate(&mut self) {
        let number = self.rng.next_u32()%11;
        self.numbers = (0..number).map(|i|self.rng.gen::<f32>()*10.0).collect();
    }

    fn guess(&mut self, n: f32) -> usize {
        self.score += 2.0_f32.powf(n);
        self.numbers.iter().filter(|i|**i<n).count()
    }
}

fn algo(which: &mut Which) {
    which.regenerate();

    loop {
        let mut guess = 1;
        while guess<=9 {
            let number = which.guess(guess as f32);
            if number >= 10 {
                return;
            }
            if (number as f32) < (guess as f32) * 0.8 {
                break
            }
            guess+=1;
        }
        which.regenerate();
    }

}

fn main() {

    let mut total_score:f64 = 0.;
    for _ in 0..10_000 {
        let mut which = Which::new(rand::thread_rng());

        algo(&mut which);
        total_score+=which.score as f64;
    }

    println!("total score: {:?}", total_score/ 10_000.);

}
```

Basic starter answer, probably not even close to optimal.

Comment: I don't, I only guess if guess `<= 9`

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, average cost = $~4975

Is that how the scoring works? I don't have time to test this another 50 million times or so rn haha

Not the best score so far, but just something I wanted to try. I do have one other idea I want to try that uses a new strategy but I'll only post it if it performs decently :P

This code checks if there are at least 5 points below 5. If there are, it goes all in and checks below 9. Either way, after that it gives up.

```js
cheater=_=>cheater()
//this crashes the program if i try to check higher than 9 :P

witch=_=>{ //witch takes no input
  let z=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
  //selects an integer from 0 to 10
  let points=[]
  for(let i=0;i<z;i++){
    points.push(Math.random()*10)
    //plots that many points on the line from 0 to 10

  }
  return x=>x>9?cheater():points.filter(w=>w<x).length
  //and returns a function which takes n as input and outputs how many points exist below n (or crashes if n>9)
}

solver=_=>{
  let current=witch()
  //calling witch generates a new set of points, which i can check with current
  let cost=0
  while(1){
    cost+=2**5
    //i pre-emptively add the cost of each inspection on the line
    if(current(5)==10){
      return cost
    }else if(current(5)>4){
    //i think its ok to use the same inspection twice at no cost, because theres no new information, and its just easier and nicer looking than storing the result in a variable or something
      cost+=2**9
      if(current(9)==10){
        return cost
      }
    }
    current=witch()
    //this is the "give up" part
  }
}

tester=(m)=>{
  //m is the number of iterations to test
  let costlist=[]
  for(let i=0;i<m;i++){
    costlist.push(solver())
  }
  return costlist.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)/costlist.length
  //returns the average cost
  //i ran tester(10000000) thrice and got 4972.0177856, 4972.7681056, and 4974.2599296.
}
```