# A multidimensional strategy challenge

Tags: code-challenge

The wizard is determined to pose the most challenging challenge yet for which he believes the previous solution techniques will not work. He  decides to go multidimensional.

If there is a number line with \$x = 10\$ then your task is to prove this. If you do so you win.  In this situation, for your code to be correct, it must correctly identify at least one such number line.

As before, the wizard will not let you choose a number larger than \$9\$. This might still be OK as you might still find 10 points and in fact the only way to win is to have found all 10 points with values 9 or less on one of the number lines.

Your goal is to devise a strategy to play at the minimum expected cost. You should report your mean cost.  To reiterate, your code should always find a line with 10 points less than or equal to 9 if one exists.

## Score

The score for your code is the expected cost to run it to completion. The lower the score the better.

Comment: Envelope idea: Take any optimal policy from the [witch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251528/114139), but modify it so that instead of starting over, any time a witch policy would start over, instead move to the next of the 100 number lines. This has zero cost, and since it's expected that you need ~32 attempts to find a valid number line, on average you never need to pay the 1000 cost to get a new set of number lines. Thus, the expected optimal cost for this problem is the same as for the witch problem

Comment: @Renaldi Even though the mean is ~32 isn't it heavy tailed?

Comment: @Renaldi Isn't 32 the mean frequency of lines that have 10 points less than 9? Isn't that very different from the frequency with which a winning line is found using the optimal witch strategy (because quite often lines are rejected which would have been good had you carried on exploring them but they didn't look good after the first few tests)?

Comment: It is, but I think as long as the policy has few false negatives on average the expected additional cost should approach zero, and the policy would still be optimal. I'll check later and see what happens

Comment: @Renaldi Thanks. I think my second comment is perhaps more relevant.  That is I thought the optimal witch strategy had a lot of false negatives.  (If it does turn out to be a problem I will reduce 100 to closer to 32.)

Comment: This was a cool one to test: For my suboptimal 2640 policy on the witch problem, I get 7.58 false negatives on average before winning, which gave an additional 2235 cost from starting over after 100 number lines. Even though the policy doesn't have to pay any additional cost ~30% of the time, and only pays at most once ~50% of the time, its FNR isn't low enough to avoid paying all the time. Assuming the optimal witch policy doesn't have a drastically lower FNR, I expect ~2610 + 2235 is going to be the score to beat

Comment: @Renaldi thanks for this. Bounty added

Comment: @Renaldi Are you working on an answer too? It would be really cool to see another approach.

Comment: I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to improve my score on the Witch problem, but if I have time I'll see if I can do something interesting for this one

Comment: @Renaldi Both of those sound awesome. I may add another bounty after this one has expired to make it more fun too.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), score = 3615.3653049197464

```python
def f(w):
    for i in range(100):
        x = w.guess(i, 1.7858708219134063)
        if (6 <= x <= 7) or (x >= 2 and w.guess(i, 4.818513589137271) >= 6): w.guess(i, 9)

print(Wizard().use(f))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJNc4IwEL3zK/aY2JYSrUId6a1XL@1MDx2HsRhsLAYmCSP0z9uNMJQoO3xMNm/ffrwtG/NdyNlD2ZTN@SyOZaEMqK3cFUfPS/Ot1vAhfrdq91alKdeavNYpL40oJF16gFYixEW2/h3PIEmEFCZJiOZ51uGt2aOfFtpADIHrVVxzQ2hP0Z7H4muN0Z9tqb794bvnhDEKWaEgASGhcwUB3bjB@SVYY7N8R4YkxZHQCQuuKWq6aWlr6@vyb/oq95UdjXXfg7iHZrTXuximk0nT30gsQVdHcoAVNBfyQ0@e60@xoT1UZBYdAwuWWJDQ3BWlxyluKiVB9oVVmndl4bOOcRJog@qu2lwPrqydvkXO4V1V3PWPyjU0o5rbiEvCVsvRO2dUttQbFL8sn9v8eJ4vxbc/13PpEzyuPc@OJyOnrmM7COGuzD9xjUqd/FZklJf5YTSPwiCasmc2ewoWM0cpsoBVjDH4CSkgL6nhBbUHXK8hzZMfsWjOZvMIWcJpiIuLsAVdDkHP1PNKJaQhbdOE@lbTjNLz@Q8)

[Try it online! (exact)](https://tio.run/##jVbbbts4EH33VxAo0JCyJItOEztFXaAF@moEKLCFYRgBdUuE2JQgyY2Y3X57dobU3XZ2/WCIo5kzl3M8dKbKp1ReL7P87S05ZGlekoMonyaTMIpJxqm0lS25rbhdsc8TAp8kJop8JYqbI35aJ7Iixhks@q2wfTtAK7x3pF05kjcggnwhHklz4jcPAT58JnlUHnNJPO1YH6iacY9ZlrAoVdxRzBx9OHLPUbw@BxYW7wbpwaeVLVjv6E8D22emr/IpkY@0rbRurE5VHA901DiJobqKJJLkQj5GlHPGZuh3r93OO0wmHwaJcEoMRnFPH49RUUAbTI@L/ENqgz7XJR6O@zKhUtmkmfs6XG13@mnTPsl0pdKVmRSWACmwiAJojEKIZj2OQkR3ZNpagAMwno7cJHNFlkUSQELWWhViKEcNMNQljE2LoXoYMsU6Okg8Gq3oCqumwkvVnVamq0IVtIFnSzot5xXitEBiEZRpnog9rdhspk1ZnoZ09BISmimHOOR1jVInebW6OMhg9AieJsBWOuY1yeg6tDcha2gWUoGGCPC83jREb@6hsPVmukV1McP0NzCh4owuwAWFcVZ26P195P2uMwwM/FcwsJaVLE9k2dXV7/Pb7Dsquy5c2Vsjb2a7rrsz@iZ0IGgQ@EjyjHxsTXNtmqMJEGAswV4UBfkrCuamHhzTw0Mik/LhgRbRPoZmoLCetNHoViieoUm10jIYMI0W4rkXX3eGKanBsp7tGsJ6Zj2E/D8g8IX13AsQYdj6/3435fS3WzVJ4Vn10yZllNcwpxj4km4NSAOwGxQdZZej4ytdw98m/o9NzJP6w64aKn4lZfD0owhEFtEfVRBlZZLKGikDh4Hfz2MQIK/vOf48iLzU3hcYHnO7BiLrjdfa8qiIStr1ac7nohOI9oamTQeIsUaKhqW@sOqr7q6z6H0DwXcjvHa1sH5wk35F9pE0PK/ZECwXSRH1R9wtSvwN6xBDbrIbtzWFtTfY5piJ497rQGs@xrTLbvDHIqpb70@uzNWw0JOhN5/YDH3YVU/enk149zbSuug3PEyzRmr2SVFS3JWm/1rVG8ZOK1o3k1@nMmInPJnArcN3g1e4@XVxc8uCFeeNOsKV3VuU3oizLjkCD66zdoHqq6W/209cgLAMxOWdYpsKgd3M0mk0RfHZ5rM0ow4/O/zXluIBw@SD7u8FCWjDcKE20xpn0z8CFFZ7n8b7VJT0KpHxFRsLq5pR/HvWzz0/k/xV5GEbKmz4D3g5u/8/svvc8wDCtyx4GNdE8a0FPOpvx2eOYFPBZhQPYGXGWl/JMX2p@cYr5cU1y4G7i@XNcuEt5/yOX3/ybq/by5Peki9w9@DXguH/WFqRrysyJwKu/yb@k7vkyxt@fbOE8MV8AXcg@NzCSBqPO8hv7t1uP1Lm6gHGjL29/Qs)

Comment: Could you explain the approach please.

Comment: It looks like you have made a strategy by some method. If you can explain your solution before the bounty expires I can award the bounty to you.

Comment: It seems your method checks at least one and at most three values \$y\$ for each line. How did you choose them?

Answer (score 2):

## R / Rcpp: 3531.3 ± 1.803

On average, the policy accrues ~3042.27 from searching number lines, and ~489 from resetting. Evaluated on 15 million simulated games. Bounds are a 95% bootstrap confidence interval with 10,000 iterations.

### Method

The policy generated for this problem was learned using the same genetic algorithm that I used in my solution to [Strategy: The cunning cousin witch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251528/114139). You can find a more detailed description of the method and policy representation there.

The difference is that for this problem I learned two policies simultaneously. For each set of 100 number lines, the first policy was active during number lines 1 - 89, and the second policy was active during number lines 90 - 100. This gave the first policy an opportunity to search more optimally early in the set of number lines, while the second policy could focus on controlling the risk of needing a new set of number lines.

### Learned Policies

The first policy is active for the first 89 number lines, attempts to minimize the cost of searching. On average, this policy passes on 2.00 number lines that would have been possible to complete per episode.

The first policy is approximately

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.00 & 1.80\\
0.50 & 0.00\\
2.30 & 1.66\\
3.44 & 2.10\\
3.46 & 2.24\\
4.76 & 2.41\\
5.45 & 9.00\\
7.37 & 9.00\\
7.77 & 9.00\\
9.00 & 3.32\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The second policy is active during the last 11 number lines, and searches the number line more aggressively in order to offset the additional cost of not completing the game in time. On average, this policy passes on 1.11 number lines that would have been possible to complete per episode.

The second policy is approximately

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.00 & 2.96\\
0.76 & 0.40\\
1.84 & 0.98\\
3.31 & 1.30\\
3.08 & 1.00\\
4.60 & 9.00\\
9.00 & 9.00\\
6.21 & 9.00\\
6.06 & 9.00\\
6.79 & 2.14\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

### Gene Importance

To better interpret the policies, it is useful to be able to measure how much each of the genes in those policies contributes to the overall score. For this problem, the matrix representing a policy is a chromosome, and each matrix address is a gene.

The problem of how to assign a fixed contribution to each gene can be thought of as a cooperative game because each gene's contribution to the overall score is mediated by all the other genes in the chromosome.

For an example of how genes affect each other, notice that in the second policy, \$p_{2}\$, that \$p_{2}(1, 1) = 0.40\$. Because \$p_{2}(0, 1) = 2.96 > 0.76 = p_{2}(1, 0)\$, the policy will never search the number line using \$p_{2}(1, 1)\$. We may say that \$p_{2}(1, 1)\$ has a contribution of zero since it is never used, but that is only because of the joint relationship between \$p_{2}(0, 1)\$ and \$p_{2}(1, 0)\$. A better option might be to assign the contribution of \$p_{2}(1, 1)\$ jointly to both \$p_{2}(0, 1)\$ and \$p_{2}(1, 0)\$. But how much total to each?

To solve this problem I calculated the contribution of each gene using Shapley additive values (SHAP values). Relevant to this problem, SHAP values have the property that the sum of all gene contributions equals the chromosome's total value, and that each gene's SHAP value equitably accounts for the conditional relationships between all the other genes.

The SHAP values for both policies are shown below compared against a trivial policy that searches the number line in units of one. The interpretation of an address in the SHAP value matrix, \$s(x, y)\$, is, "Replacing address \$p(x, y)\$ in the trivial policy with its value in the learned policy changes the policy's total score by \$s(x, y)\$ on average."

The SHAP value matrix for the first policy is approximately

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.53 & -318.01\\
148.98 & -0.75\\
-1.04 & -10.96\\
0.69 & -48.22\\
-2.68 & -86.70\\
-28.58 & -65.90\\
-51.29 & -239.74\\
17.75 & -357.69\\
-3.87 & -258.72\\
0.39 & -67.08\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The SHAP value matrix for the second policy is approximately

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.49 & -19.24\\
9.60 & 4.60\\
6.43 & 2.90\\
-0.21 & -3.16\\
-0.55 & -1.97\\
-4.93 & -27.43\\
11.70 & -52.22\\
-1.75 & -37.09\\
16.48 & -27.57\\
39.71 & -4.86\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Recall that these SHAP values are in comparison to the trivial policy of searching in units of one, not to a random policy. Given that the score of the trivial policy is about 4994.913, and the sums of both SHAP matrices are about -1373.944 and -89.07059 respectively, adding the values together gives 4994.913 - 1373.944 - 89.07059 = 3531.898, which is nearly the score we get from evaluating the learned policy directly.

Note: Because this is a minimization problem, more negative SHAP values are better since they represent a decrease in total cost.

### Code

The code used to run the genetic algorithm is nearly equivalent to my solution linked at the top of this answer, so here I include only the code used to define the algorithm itself where it differs from my previous implementation.

**Rcpp code to Define the Genetic Algorithm**

```
//* Generate Chromosome
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector generateChromosome() {
  NumericVector chrom (40);
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    if(i == 0 | i == 10){
      chrom[i] = 0;
    } else {
      chrom[i] = chrom[i - 1] + Rcpp::runif(1, 0.0, 2.0)[0];
    }
  }
  for(int i = 20; i < 40; i++){
    chrom[i] = Rcpp::runif(1, 0.0, 2.0)[0];
  }
  return(Rcpp::clamp(0.0, chrom, 9.0));
}

//* Chromosome to Policy
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix chromToPolicy(NumericVector x) {
  NumericVector policy = clone(x);
  policy[0] = 0.0;
  policy.attr("dim") = Dimension(20, 2);
  return(as<NumericMatrix>(policy));
}

//* Evaluate Chromosome
//* Note: The cost of resetting (1000) isn't hardcoded here
//* Instead, the number of resets per episode is counted
//* The cost penalty is applied in a chromosome fitness function instead
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix evaluatePolicy(
    NumericVector x,
    int iters,
    int maxCost = -1
) {
  
  //Convert chromosome to policy
  NumericMatrix policy = chromToPolicy(x);
  
  //Run episodes
  NumericMatrix out (iters, 6);
  bool earlyStop = false;
  for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++){
    
    //Initialize values
    NumericVector points = setPoints();
    double lineSearched = 0;
    int ptsFound = 0;
    int lineCount = 1;
    int polNum = 0;
    
    //Begin episode
    bool done = false;
    while(!done) {
      
      //Step forward if in policy
      if(policy(ptsFound + polNum, 0) >= lineSearched){
        lineSearched += policy(ptsFound + polNum, 1);
        if(lineSearched > 9){
          lineSearched = 9;
        }
        out(i, 0) += pow(2, lineSearched);
        ptsFound = sum(points <= lineSearched);
        
      } else {
        
        //Otherwise, reset
        //Code result
        if(sum(points <= 9) == 10){
          out(i, 4) += 1;
        } else {
          out(i, 2) += 1;
        }
        
        //Reset values
        points = setPoints();
        lineSearched = 0;
        ptsFound = 0;
        
        //Increase line count
        lineCount += 1;
        if(lineCount == 101){
          lineCount = 1;
          polNum = 0;
          out(i, 1) += 1;
        } else {
          //Integer division -> floor(lineCount / 10)
          if(lineCount / 10 + 1 > 9){
            polNum = 10;
          }
        }
        
      }
      
      //Reset when line searched but fewer than 10 points found
      if(lineSearched == 9 & ptsFound < 10){
        
        //Code result
        out(i, 3) += 1;
        
        //Reset values
        points = setPoints();
        lineSearched = 0;
        ptsFound = 0;
        
        //Increase line count
        lineCount += 1;
        if(lineCount == 101){
          lineCount = 1;
          polNum = 0;
          out(i, 1) += 1;
        } else {
          //Integer division -> floor(lineCount / 10)
          if(lineCount / 10 + 1 > 9){
            polNum = 10;
          }
        }
        
      }
      
      //Exit conditions
      if(ptsFound == 10){
        out(i, 5) += 1;
        done = true;
      }
      
      //Early stop condition
      if((maxCost >= 0 & out(i, 0) >= maxCost)){
        out(i, 0) = NA_REAL;
        earlyStop = true;
        done = true;
      }
      
    }
    if(earlyStop){
      break;
    }
  }

  //Return
  return(out);

}
```

**R Code for the SHAP Algorithm**

````
# Characterize trivial policy
trivChrom <- c(0:9, 0:9, rep(1, 20))
trivOut <- evaluatePolicy(trivChrom, 15000000, 1000000)
trivOut <- mean(trivOut[, 1] + 1000 * trivOut[, 2])

# Characterize full policy
x <- readRDS(r"minPolicy_3472_121.rds")
evOut <- evaluatePolicy(x, 15000000, 1000000)
evOut <- mean(evOut[, 1] + 1000 * evOut[, 2])

# Initialize parameters
tol <- 5
iters <- 500

# Shapley algorithm
shapVals <- rep(0, length(x))

t <- 0
while(TRUE){
  
  # Increment t
  t <- t + 1
  
  # Permute the gene order
  geneOrder <- sample(1:length(x), length(x), replace = FALSE)
  
  # Calculate shap value
  shapPol <- trivChrom
  v <- rep(NA, length(x) + 1)
  v[1] <- trivOut
  for(j in 1:length(x)){
    if(abs(evOut - v[j]) < tol){
      v[j + 1] = v[j]
    } else {
      shapPol[geneOrder[j]] = x[geneOrder[j]]
      shapEv = evaluatePolicy(shapPol, 100000, 10000000)
      shapEv = mean(shapEv[, 1] + 1000 * shapEv[, 2])
      v[j + 1] = ifelse(is.na(shapEv), v[j], shapEv)
    }
    shapVals[geneOrder[j]] = (t - 1) / t * shapVals[geneOrder[j]] + (1 / t) * (v[j + 1] - v[j])
  }
  
  # Exit conditions
  if(t >= iters){
    break
  }
  
}
```
````

Comment: This is great, thank you. How far from optimal do you think this is?

Comment: I definitely think there is improvement to be made. Optimizing the individual policies will probably score some more points, and I especially think there's value in trying to exploit the problem structure in a less naïve way than I did for this solution

Answer (score 2):

## Python, average cost = 3498 +/- 5

Shamelessly steals the policy from Renaldi (thanks!), but always applies it to the number line with the highest probability of having 10 points instead of going through them one at a time. I tried to incorporate the backup policy, but that ended up making things worse. I'm not sure why my Gittin's Index answer doesn't work very well; I guess some assumption must be subtly violated or I have a bug somewhere.

```
import heapq
import functools
import random

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom

def logsumexp(x):
    m = x.max()
    return np.log(np.sum(np.exp(x - m))) + m

@functools.lru_cache(None)
def log_p_win(a, n):
    k = np.arange(n, 11)
    u = np.zeros(k.shape) if a == 0 else binom(k, a / 10).logpmf(n)
    d = binom(k - n, (9 - a) / (10 - a))
    t = np.zeros(11 - n)
    for i in range(11 - n):
        t[i] = logsumexp(u + d.logpmf(i))
    return t[-1] - logsumexp(t)

policy = [
    [0, 0.5, 2.3, 3.44, 3.46, 4.76, 5.45, 7.37, 7.77, 9],
    [1.8, 0, 1.66, 2.1, 2.24, 2.41, 9, 9, 9, 3.32],
]

while True:
    mean_cost = 0
    sse_cost = 0
    queue = []
    done = True
    trials = 0
    cost = 0
    while True:
        if done or not queue:
            if not done:
                cost += 1000
            lines = [
                [random.uniform(0, 10) for _ in range(random.randrange(11))]
                for _ in range(100)
            ]
            del queue[:]
            for i, _ in enumerate(lines):
                heapq.heappush(queue, (-log_p_win(0, 0), 0, 0, i))
        done = False
        v, n, a, i = heapq.heappop(queue)
        if a <= policy[0][n]:
            a = min(9, a + policy[1][n])
        else:
            continue
        cost += 2 ** a
        n = sum(1 for x in lines[i] if x <= a)
        if n == 10:
            done = True
            trials += 1
            d = (cost - mean_cost)
            mean_cost += d / trials
            sse_cost += d * (cost - mean_cost)
            if trials % 100 == 0:
                print(trials, mean_cost, np.sqrt(sse_cost) / trials)
            cost = 0
            continue
        if a == 9:
            continue
        v = -log_p_win(a, n)
        heapq.heappush(queue, (v, n, a, i))
```

Comment: This is a cool idea! I tried to code up a version to play with, but when I run it I get the same ~3531 score (~3577 without the second policy), so maybe I'm not understanding exactly how your version works. Can you say more about what cases it improves on? I see that it's rejecting lines using the policy directly, so I'm interpreting this as being an improvement when the policy hasn't rejected a line yet but that line's -log_p_win() is greater than ~3.45. Am I understanding the code correctly?

Comment: Please disregard my earlier comment - I'm getting the same answer as you now. It helps when you actually use log_p_win() to select a new line and don't just calculate it for fun

Comment: I believe you can do better than this still. I have added a non time limited bounty.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, score ~= 3922

Repurposes some of my code from the Witch challenge. Uses a Gittins Index strategy, where the cost of resetting is estimated empirically.

```python
import heapq
import functools
import random

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom

bound = 16153
samples = 50

g = np.linspace(0, 9, samples)

def logsumexp(x):
    m = x.max()
    return np.log(np.sum(np.exp(x - m))) + m

def init_trans(samples):
    print("computing transition matrix...\n")
    trans = np.full((samples, 10, samples, 11), float('-inf'))
    g = np.linspace(0, 9, samples)
    for i0 in range(samples - 1):
        print(f"computing row {i0} of {samples}", end='\r', flush=True)
        g0 = g[i0]
        for n in range(10):
            k = np.arange(n, 11)
            u = np.zeros(k.shape) if i0 == 0 else binom(k, g0 / 10).logpmf(n)
            for i1 in range(i0 + 1, samples):
                g1 = g[i1]
                d = binom(k - n, (g1 - g0) / (10 - g0))
                for m in range(n, 11):
                    v = d.logpmf(m - n)
                    trans[i0,n,i1,m] = logsumexp(u + v)
    print()
    trans -= trans.max(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    trans = np.exp(trans)
    trans /= trans.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    return trans

trans = init_trans(samples)

@functools.lru_cache(None)
def gittins_value(i0, n0, v0):
    if n0 == 10:
        return (0, None)
    if i0 == samples - 1:
        return (v0, None)
    v = v0
    i = None
    for i1 in range(i0 + 1, samples):
        v1 = sum(trans[i0,n0,i1,n1] * (2 ** g[i1] + gittins_value(i1, n1, v0)[0]) for n1 in range(n0, 11))
        if v1 <= v:
            v = v1
            i = i1
    return (v, i)

@functools.lru_cache(None)
def gittins_index(i0, n0):
    low = 0
    high = bound
    best_action = i0 + 1
    while high - low >= 1e-9:
        mid = low + 0.5 * (high - low)
        v, i1 = gittins_value(i0, n0, mid)
        if v == mid:
            low = mid
        else:
            high = mid
            best_action = i1
    return high, best_action

mean_cost = 0
reset_cost = bound
queue = []
reset = True
trials = 0
cost = 0
while True:
    if reset:
        lines = [
            [random.uniform(0, 10) for _ in range(random.randrange(11))]
            for _ in range(100)
        ]
        del queue[:]
        for i, _ in enumerate(lines):
            heapq.heappush(queue, gittins_index(0, 0) + (i,))
    reset = False
    v, a, i = heapq.heappop(queue)
    if v > 1000 + reset_cost:
        cost += 1000
        reset = True
        continue
    cost += 2 ** g[a]
    n = sum(1 for x in lines[i] if x <= g[a])
    if n == 10:
        reset = True
        trials += 1
        mean_cost += (cost - mean_cost) / trials
        reset_cost += (cost - reset_cost) / (trials + 100)
        cost = 0
        print(trials, mean_cost)
        continue
    if a == samples - 1:
        reset = not queue
        continue
    heapq.heappush(queue, (gittins_index(a, n) + (i,)))
```

Comment: Wow! I'm curious, how much of the score is from guessing values and how much is from resetting?

Comment: @Renaldi Looks like resetting only adds about 320 on average.

Comment: The output is interesting in that it isn't monotonically decreasing at all. Could you add a little explanation of what it is doing?

Comment: I also get "multidim.py:34: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  trans -= trans.max(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
"

Comment: @graffe I think it only effects entries which aren't used

Comment: Does your method ever skip values on a line? That is choose a value, then next time skip a lot of values it could have chosen and choose a bigger one? I think you can get a better score if you allow that.

Comment: @graffe Yes, if I understand what you're asking. It always considers all possible values larger than the previously chosen value.

Comment: That is interesting. I think a better score is possible but I am not then sure why your method doesn't find it

Comment: @graffe what makes you think so?

Comment: @user1502040 If you run the optimal witch strategy but just charge 10 dollars for every new line you get a lower score. I mean change the method for finding the optimal witch strategy so that this charge is built in.

Comment: @graffe What is your best score?

Comment: 3840 is what I get just by that crude method.

Comment: It seems the other answer has got an amazingly good score unless you can see a bug in it?